# Зачем простое условие для if обрамлять скобами в c++?

Tags: c++, if

```
int a=25;
bool b=true;
if b
{
cout<<a<<endl;
}
```

Выдаёт ошибку во время компиляции и требует поставить скобы `(b)`, хотя условие "односложное". Будь условие `a!=1 && a!=2` вопрос бы и не возникал по поводу скоб, но условие простое.

Comment: коротко - это не паскаль) тут так надо

Comment: @pavel а ещё в lua с этим проблем нет, и в питоне, и (как Вы пишете) в паскале. В чём причина такого действа в c++?

Comment: @Глеб зато в `python` у вас есть двоеточия, а в `lua` и `паскаль` ключевое слово `then`. Так реализован парсер выражений, чтобы точно определять положение условий и потому синтаксис требует скобки. В итоге никаких противоречий и проверять легче.

Comment: @Harry я могу дать совет начать задавать себе логичные вопросы и искать ответ, вместо того, чтобы забрасывать вопрос на дальнюю полку, аргументируя, что "до меня так было, надо выучить, а не понимать".

Comment: @Alex Krass в случае отсутствия открывающей скобки сразу после if окончанием условия мог бы быть первый пробел или знак конца строки или знак переноса каретки. Вот и условие для парсера, которое всегда верно вычислит конец условия if при отсутствии скоб, ключевого слова и односложном условии из одной переменной типа bool

Comment: В чём смысл таких вопросов?

Comment: Ну, у нас, видимо, разные понятия о логике :) Ваши вопросы - просто выражение эмоций: какой дебильный этот С++. Потому что ну никак не могу поверить, что, подумав 5-10 минут, не удастся найти ответы на такого рода вопросы самостоятельно... Поэтому и советую найти язык, который не будет вызывать такую реакцию. Понимаете, по вашей реакции видно, что вы не стремитесь разобраться с языком, а ищете повод с ним не разбираться :) Хорошо хоть не было еще классического "в компиляторе наверняка ошибка - он не компилирует мой исходник!" :)

Comment: @Harry ветка скатывается в оффтоп. По поводу моей логики: перечитайте мои слова, возможно, слишком быстрое прочтение не дало вникнуть. Я не давал негативную оценку с++. Конкретно по моим вопросам беглый поиск в гугле ничего не дал по теме, только смежное. По Вашей реакции видно тупой тезис "запомни наизусть и не спрашивай ни о чём". Мой совет выше в силе и, обращая внимание на этот оффтоп, советую применить мой совет выше не только к С++. И впредь советую избегать перехода на обсуждение чего-либо кроме темы вопроса, модераторы существуют.

Comment: @Глеб, может вас это удивит, разработчики языка Си (С++ потом унаследовал его синтаксис, но это уже совсем другая история) делали его в первую очередь **сами для себя**. Далее, те кому он понравился стали его использовать и развивать, по возможности сохраняя совместимость с предыдущими решениями.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что бред

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы не забывайте, что предложение `if` может быть записано в одну строчку. Например,

```
bool b = true;
int x = 1;
int *p = &x;

if ( b ) * p += x;
```

Если убрать скобки, то получим

```
bool b = true;
int x = 1;
int *p = &x;

if b * p += x;
```

Что совершенно нечитаемо.

Единственное, что вы можете поместить вне скобок в предложении `if`, это ключевое слово `constexpr`, что стало возможно с появлением стандарта C++17.

Можете ознакомиться с простым примером использования такого синтаксиса на моем персональном форуме по ссылке [Новый синтаксис предложения if в стандарте C++ 17](http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-1-0-00000112-000-0-0-1542096379)  и [Как выполнить инверсию отдельных слов в объекте класса std::string](http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-1-0-00000106-000-0-0-1541684397)

Comment: ещё перед скобами можно было бы расположить знак отрицания условия `!(bool)`, но это тоже ошибка компилятора. чем больше думаю про плюсы, тем больше нравится питон.

Comment: @Глеб: "Знак отрицания" в С и С++ не обладает каким-то особым статусом. Это такой же оператор в выражениях, как и любой другой оператор.

Comment: @AnT но Вы же согласитесь, что иногда хотелось бы иметь доступ к инверсии условия и получить его быстро, написав перед условием отрицание (в пару знаков)? Скажем, ключевое слово not не нарушило бы логику парсера, если бы расположилось так `if not (bool)` (если такой вариант событий будет добавлен в парсер), либо стандартный в cpp знак отрицания `!`. либо реализовать оператор ветвления `ifnot (bool) elseifnot (bool) elseif (bool) else`, который сразу бы брал отрицание от условия.

Comment: Синтаксический сахар. `if not (condition)` и `if (!condition)` различны только в написании условия и доп слове. А зарезервированных слов в c++ достаточно. Это того не стоит.

Answer (score 4):

Ну а как вы прочитаете:

```
if b -- a; //???
```

это :

```
if(b) --a;
if(b--) a;
if (b -- a);
```

какой из этих выражений имел ввиду программист? Не говоря уж о других выражениях, где могут встречаться символы_операторы, приоритет которых выше, и тогда нужно это выражение с начала считать, потом пытаться проверять какое то условие.  Просто язык писали умные люди, и синтаксис инструкций придуман совершенно разумный

Comment: Опять же, `Просто язык писали умные ` субъективная оценка, не требуемая вопросом. Поясните, почему отсутствие ключевого слова окончания условия является умным ходом? А присутствие `:` в питоне (исходя из Ваших слов) решением не умных людей. Как уже писал выше, в случае отсутствия открывающей скобы сразу после if окончанием условия мог бы служить первый пробел или знак переноса строки. Таким образом без ключевого слова окончания условия и при коротком условии из одной переменной типа bool можно было бы верно определять конец условия, на мой взгляд. Но это не реализовано, какие этому причины?

Comment: по вашим примерам: `if (b) --a; --> if b --a;` `if (b--) a; --> if b-- a;` `if (b -- a); --> if b--a;` Дело в пробелах. Но в конкретном случае я говорю не о двух аргументах. Перечитайте вопрос, он об единственной переменной типа bool. (и чаще всего в моём опыте встречается именно такая конструкция `bool isValue; if isValue {}`)

Comment: вы просто хотите спорить а не понимать. Дело ваше...

Comment: @Глеб Если Вам не нравится синтаксис языка, то вряд-ли под Вас этот синтаксис изменят. Попробуйте использовать другой язык с другим синтаксисом, если же нет такой возможности (Вам по каким-то причинам необходимо использовать кресты) то выход остаётся один - смириться.